# Redirect loop occuring while removing/adding trailing Slash from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

While writing a rewrite rule specifically for only a particular URL to remove a trailing slash from it, an infinite redirect loop is occuring.

The following is the code I am trying to code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^abc.php /abc/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^abc/ abc.php [NC,QSA]
```

I am trying to make a 301 Redirect on abc.php to abc/ but want to serve abc/ with abc.php's content only. Want to write a Rule specifically for this url only.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to hide the `.php` from the URL for that particular case, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but I also want to make a 301 redirect to abc/ and want to apply this rule only to abc.php

Comment: how about reversing the order of the rules? As in `RewriteRule ^abc/ abc.php [NC,L,QSA]` before `RewriteRule ^abc.php /abc/ [R=301,L,NC,QSA]` . Since the desired URL is /abc/ and rules are read from top down

Comment: it won't work.. won't change the flow that happens

Comment: Anyway, this is what I tried and I think it fixed it on my machine but let me know how it goes! Basically I added `?` to the `/` in the `^abc/` to become `RewriteRule ^abc/? abc.php [NC,QSA]` .

Comment: It won't help because a redirect wouldn't be possible then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the infinite loop if you check the HTTP request line (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and also [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1)) sent to the server by the browser with a `RewriteCond` and, in addition, you reverse the order of the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/ abc.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /abc\.php
RewriteRule ^abc.php$ /abc/ [R=301, QSA]
```

Comment: I can have both GET and POST requests at these URLs, hence it can become a problem.

Comment: Couldn't you add a new condition for the POST case and combine both conditions with an [OR] flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc/? abc.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^abc.php /abc/ [R=301,QSA]
```

Hope it helps!